# MySQL In query with Array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my status code array = [1,2,3,4,5], and in my Claim table status_code is there. In that I store status code. Now I want find those Claim that have status code [1,2,4]. Then How can I find.

I write this query : Claim.where("status_code IN (1,2)") that workings but I need to pass array. So How can I pass array in 'In' query.

Thanks For Help.

Comment: You can see the generated SQL: `Claim.where(status_code: [1,2,3]).to_sql` || Another tip: `Claim.where(status_code: 1..5)`

Comment: What kind of type is `status_code`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming status_code is integer type. You can directly use the array in where clause.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
Claim.where(status_code: array)
```

OR

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
Claim.where('claims.status_code IN (?)', array)
```

Comment: Why is it that you can't just put the array directly in the query?